# How to edit DLL file for asp.NET website

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dll

I'm working on a website which has a form where the entries get uploaded into a database. I want to add a new field called 'CreatedDate' which will store the date of the submission. When I added the new field I am getting this error:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'CreatedDate' is not a member of
>   'AmsServices.Contacts'.

MY code looks like this:

```
Try
            Dim objContat As Contacts = New Contacts()
            Dim dr As DataRow
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim MaxIDValue As String
            objContat.FirstName = Trim(txtFirstName.Text)
            objContat.LastName = Trim(txtLastName.Text)
            objContat.EmailAddress = Trim(txtEmailAddress.Text)
            objContat.PhoneNumber = Trim(txtPhoneNumber.Text)
            objContat.Company = Trim(txtCompany.Text)
            objContat.Address = Trim(txtAddress.Text)
            objContat.Address2 = Trim(txtAddress2.Text)
            objContat.City = Trim(txtFirstName.Text)
            objContat.State = Trim(ddListStates.SelectedItem.Text)
            objContat.ZipCode = Trim(txtZipCode.Text)
            objContat.Comments = Trim(txtComments.Text)
            objContat.DateCreated = Now()

            'added to store the created date
            objContat.CreatedDate = Now()

            objContat.Insert()
```

It looks like Contacts() is an array with predefined keys and my new field 'DateCreated' is not one of those keys. I tracked this down to a file called AmsServices.dll in the bin folder, where it appears that 'Contacts()' is being defined, but when I open the file in NotePad++ I can only get unreadable gibberish. Opening the file as HEX is a little better, but I don't know how I would edit it. The file looks something like this:

```
<Module><nul>AmsServices.dll<nul>Command<nul>AmsServices<nul>ChangeAddress<nul>OneTimePaymentObj<nul>LossMitigationObject<nul>DataManager<nul>Parameter<nul>Contacts<nul>mscorlib<nul>System<nul>Object<nul>_sProcName<nul>System.Collections.Generic<nul>List`1<nul>_sProcParameters<nul>GetParameters<nul>GetName<nul>.ctor<nul>AddParameter<nul>_ID<nul>_FirstName<nul>_LastName<nul>_Address<nul>_Address2<nul>_City<nul>_State<nul>_ZipCode<nul>_PhoneNumber<nul>_MobilePhone<nul>_WorkPhone<nul>_OtherPhone<nul>_EmailAddress<nul>_Comments<nul>DateTime<nul>_DateCreated<nul>get_ID<nul>set_ID<nul>get_FirstName<nul>set_FirstName<nul>get_LastName<nul>set_LastName<nul>get_Address<nul>set_Address<nul>get_Address2<nul>set_Address2
```

I'm guessing that I need to open this file in a special program to edit the definition of 'Contacts()' but I'm not sure what program I need to use. Can anyone give some direction on how I can edit this file?

Thanks

Comment: see if you solution has a project named "AmsServices". you should have a "Contacts" class in it with properties defined, add "CreatedDate" property to it and build you solution

Comment: What is the storage system? SQL Server?

Comment: You can't simply "edit the DLL" file. You need to change what you want in the source and rebuild to generate a new DLL file. Assuming if course you have access to the source.

Comment: I do not have access to the source, only the compiled files that were downloaded from the host. Does this mean I will need to rebuild that script in order to add a new field to my form?

Comment: @mclaassen http://i.imgur.com/x02Jrb6.jpg

Comment: In that case you will need to have a new DLL with the property attached to it

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question. What program should I be using to build and compile this? Can I use Microsoft Visual Studio Express?

Comment: @user2339691 In that case there's not really anything you can do unless you can convince the authors of the DLL to make the changes you require.